# Returning an array of structs from a recursive huffman tree C

Tags: c

i have a task in class to the return an array of struck Symbol from huffman tree. 
the function getSL get a huffman tree(only) and return struck of Symbol.
each spot in the array contain a char from the "leaf" of the tree and the
length of his code(how many cross section till the leaf).
my main problem was to find how i advance the cnt of the arry that it will not overright the arry.
thank you.

```
typedef  struct  HNode {
    char  chr;
    struct HNode *left, *right;
} HNode;

typedef  struct {
    char chr;
    int counter;
}Symbol;
```

this is what i did till now.

```
Symbol * getSL(HNode *root) {

    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
        Symbol* b = (Symbol*)malloc(100);
        b->counter=0;
        b->chr = root->chr;
        return b;
    }
    Symbol* a = (Symbol*)malloc(100);

    if (root->left != NULL) {
        a= getSL(root->left);
        a->counter++;
    }

    if (root->right != NULL) {
        a= getSL(root->right);
        a->counter++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Do a dry run to count. Then allocate the arrays, then run again, or use `reallocate`

Comment: Pls wrte in englsh and dont abrvate. ;-)

Comment: BTW You have memory leak.

Comment: `Symbol* b = (Symbol*)malloc(100);` most likely allocates wrong number of bytes (100), and has unnecessary cast. Perhaps you meant to write `Symbol* b = malloc(sizeof *b);`?

Comment: i know that i may have problems with the malloc, but it's not the question that i asked. unless it will solve the question?

Comment: The logic of counting the number occurrences of a given character is completely lacking in your `getSL` example.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the malloc problem (see the comments already), you have a fundamental problem: You allocate a new struct, but then *replace* it with the one returned from the recursive call. So you lose the one created before (actually, memory leaking!).

Easiest variant would now be converting your Symbol to linked list nodes; then you simply could do:

```
Symbol* lastLeafFound; // probaly a function parameter!

if(!(root->left || root->right))
{
    // leaf found:
    Symbol* a = (Symbol*)malloc(sizeof(Symbol));
    a->chr = root->chr;
    a->counter = /* ... */;
    a->next = NULL;
    lastLeafFound->next = a;
    // you might return a now as last leaf found, using it in the next recursive call
}
```

Sure, above code is incomplete, but should give you the idea...

If you cannot modify your struct, then you need to create an array and pass it on to every new recursive call (prefer not to use global variables instead):

```
void doGetSL
(
    HNode* root,
    Symbol** symbols,      // your array to be used
    unsigned int* count,   // number of symbols contained so far
    unsigned int* capacity // maximum possible symbols
)
```

Passing all data as pointers allows the function to modify them as needed and they are still available from outside...

```
Symbol* getSL(HNode* root)
{
    if(!root)
        return NULL;

    unsigned int count = 0;
    unsigned int capacity = 128;
    // allocate a whole array:
    Symbol* array = malloc(capacity*sizeof(Symbol));

    if(array) // malloc could fail...
    {
        doGetSL(root, &array, &count, &capacity);

        // as you cannot return the number of leaves together with
        // the array itself, you will need a sentinel:
        array[count].chr = 0;
        // obvious enough, I'd say, alternatively you could
        // set counter to 0 or -1 (or set both chr and counter) 
    }
    return array;
}
```

`doGetSL` will now use above set up "infrastructure":

```
{
    if(!(root->left || root->right))
    {
        if(*count == *capacity)
        {
            // no memory left -> we need a larger array!

            // store in separate variables:
            unsigned int c = *capacity * 2;
            Symbol* s = realloc(symbols, c * sizeof(Symbol));
            // now we can check, if reallocation was successful
            // (on failure, s will be NULL!!!):
            if(s)
            {
                // OK, we can use them...
                *symbols = s; // <- need a pointer for (pointer to pointer)!
                *capacity = c;
            }
            else
            {
                // re-allocation failed!
                // -> need appropriate error handling!
            }
        }

        (*symbols)[count].chr = root->chr;
        (*symbols)[count].counter = /*...*/;
        ++*count;

    }
    else
    {
        if(root->left)
        {
            doGetSL(root->left, symbols, count, capacity);
        }
        if(root->right)
        {
            doGetSL(root->right, symbols, count, capacity);
        }
    }
}
```

One thing yet omitted: setting the counter. That would be quite easy: add another parameter to `doGetSL` indicating the current depth, which you increment right when entering doGetSL, you can then just assign this value when needed.

You can further improve above variant (especially readability), if you introduce a new struct:

```
struct SLData
{
    Symbol* symbols,      // your array to be used
    unsigned int count,   // number of symbols contained so far
    unsigned int capacity // maximum possible symbols
};
```

and pass this one instead of the three pointers:

```
doGetSL(HNode*, struct SLData*, unsigned int depth);

struct SLData data = 
{
    .count = 0;
    .capacity = 128;
    .array = malloc(capacity*sizeof(Symbol));
};
if(data.array)
    doGetSL(root, &data, 0); // again passed as pointer!
```